# SQL arrange row in column

Tags: sql, pivot

I have following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    PatientMRN,
    OrderDate,
    PatientMRN,
    OrdereName,
FROM OrderItem
```

For some MRN patient have many orders and I would like to have order related to each patient in a column rather than have duplicate row of same MRN with different order.
So instead of having:

```
MRN  OrdereName
012  Name one
012  Name two
012  Name three
012  Name four
```

I want to have it as follow:

```
MRN  OrdereName1 OrderName2 OrderName3 
012  Name one    Name two   Name three
```

unfortunately it is a confidential DB so I can attach it here.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance the maximum number of orders per patient, you can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select patientmrn,
    max(case when rn = 1 then orderename end) as orderename1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then orderename end) as orderename2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then orderename end) as orderename3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by patientmrn order by orderename) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by patientmrn
```

You can expand the `select` clause with more conditional `max()` as needed (additional columns show `null` values when there is no more orders to display).

You control how orders are spread in the columns using the `order by` clause of the `row_number()`. Here, orders are orderes by ascending name. If, for example, you wanted to order them by date, you would change the `order by` clause to `order by orderdate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. Though, it says SQLUSER.ROW_Number does not exist.

Comment: @Ohoud0: that's standard SQL, that most databases support... Which database are you running?

Comment: sorry for missing that, it  is cache DB.